# no module named urllib.parse (How should I install it?)

Tags: python, django, urllib

I'm trying to run a REST API on CentOS 7, I read urllib.parse is in Python 3 but I'm using Python 2.7.5 so I don't know how to install this module.

I installed all the requirements but still can't run the project.

When I'm looking for a URL I get this (I'm using the browsable interface):

Output:

```
ImportError at /stamp/
No module named urllib.parse
```

Answer (score 106):

If you need to write code which is Python2 and Python3 compatible you can use the following import

```
try:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
except ImportError:
     from urlparse import urlparse
```

Answer (score 28):

You want urlparse using python2:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
```

Answer (score 24):

With the information you have provided, your best bet will be to use Python 3.x.

Your error suggests that the code may have been written for Python 3 given that it is trying to import `urllib.parse`. If you've written the software and have control over its source code, you **should** change the import to:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
```

`urllib` was split into `urllib.parse`, `urllib.request`, and `urllib.error` in Python 3.

I suggest that you take a quick look at software collections in CentOS **if you are not able to change** the imports for some reason.
You can bring in Python 3.3 like this:

1. `yum install centos­-release­-SCL`
2. `yum install python33`
3. `scl enable python33`

Check [this](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) page out for more info on SCLs

Answer (score 17):

`python3` supports `urllib.parse` and `python2` supports `urlparse`

If you want both compatible then the following code can help.

```
import sys

if ((3, 0) <= sys.version_info <= (3, 9)):
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
elif ((2, 0) <= sys.version_info <= (2, 9)):
    from urlparse import urlparse
```

**Update**: Change if condition to support higher versions `if (3, 0) <= sys.version_info:`.

Comment: This would break in Python 3.10 ;)

Answer (score 13):

Install [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/), the Python 2 and 3 Compatibility Library:

```
$ sudo -H pip install six
```

Use it:

```
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlparse
```

(edit: I deleted the other answer)

Comment: lol, q: "No module named urllib.parse" a: install third party lib to do try..except for you xD . worst answer ever

Comment: IMO, this is the right answer. Six is an incredibly useful module for writing python2/3 compatible code. You can have four lines and an ugly try/catch, or you can just use six.

Comment: @Reishin Six is the sixt most downloaded Python package in 2015 - only setuptools, requests, virtualenv, distribute and boto are downloaded more often (see [my analysis](https://martin-thoma.com/analyzing-pypi-metadata/)). Chances are good that an experienced Python developer will have this already installed.

Comment: it is most downloaded as 90% of "developers" blindly copy-paste recipes from here with no knowledge about best practices.  Well, at the end it is "dev" choice to overcrowd his product with 3d party libs, where he use only one function, which can be easily done by native python bu it results in shitty application with thousands of dependencies and shitty optimization.

Comment: @DanR or you can wrap this try..catch in a function and use it....what a hell; or import it in __init__  with `as` directive, and then re-import it from that package. But no, you need to use tons of code and dependencies for just nicely looking import

Comment: @Reishin - Anytime you're developing software, you have to weigh your decisions when adding dependencies. There's risk in doing everything in Native Python because it creates more code that you have to manage, debug, unit test, etc. There's risk in bringing in modules because you're trusting the maintainers of the other package to properly maintain them. And odds are that if you're trying to write code that is python2/3 compatible, you will be using more than just this from six. I use it in many places.

Answer (score 5):

For python 3 
   pip install urllib

find the `utils.py` in %PYTHON_HOME%\Lib\site-packages\solrcloudpy\utils.py

change the `import urlparse` to

```
from urllib import parse as urlparse
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3, use the following:

```
import urllib.parse
```

Answer (score 1):

The urlparse in Python 2.7.11 was renamed to urllib.parse in Python 3.
So, if you have a code such from urlparse import urlparse, I suggest you change it to from urllib.parse import urlparse
Since you are using python 2.7.5, using the below will solve your poblem

```
from urlparse import urlparse
```

Instead of `from urllib.parse import urlparse`

Answer (score 1):

according to:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

python 2x

```
from urlparse import urlparse
```

python 3x

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

Answer (score 0):

Manually include urllib.parse: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse

Answer (score -2):

The problem was because I had a lower version of Django (1.4.10), so Django Rest Framework need at least Django 1.4.11 or bigger. Thanks for their answers guys!

Here the link for the requirements of Django Rest: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Answer (score -10):

```
pip install -U websocket
```

I just use this to fix my problem

Comment: I've see that answer somewhere, and even if that does solve the problem because has urlparse as dependancy, is not the proper way to solve it.